# Setting up HttpContext for .Net Unit Tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, moq, httpcontext

I'm writing an unit test(using `NUnit` & `MOQ`) for an action method `MethodUnderTest` which uses `HttpContext` internally to do some functionality. I'm setting up a fake hosting environment by calling `InitializeHostingEnvironment`  where I'm initializing the session like:

```cs
public static HttpSessionState InitializeSession()
{
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", "");
    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
    var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

    HttpContext.Current = httpContext;
    HttpContext.Current.Items.Clear();
    HttpSessionState session = (HttpSessionState)ReflectionHelper.Instantiate(typeof(HttpSessionState), new Type[] { typeof(IHttpSessionState) }, new FakeHttpSessionState());

    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("AspSession", session);

    return session;
}

public static void InitializeHostingEnvironment(string userName, string password)
{
     // lines of code
     InitializeSession();
}
```

I'm calling the `InitializeHostingEnvironment()` from my Test Method like so:

```cs
public static void Test_MethodUnderTest()
{
    InitializeHostingEnvironment(UN, PW);
    MethodUnderTest(param1, param2, param3); -- getting exception while trying to execute this line
}
```

While trying to execute the line `MethodUnderTest(param1, param2, param3);`, I'm getting an exception - `System.ArgumentNullException - Value cannot be null. Parameter name httpBrowserCapabilities`. Stack trace is given below:
[image]

Since the exception says `httpBrowserCapabilities` is null, I tried to initialize it like `HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities();` inside the `InitializeSession()` method, but now, I'm getting another exception:
[image]

What should I do now? Is the way I'm initializing `HttpContext` wrong? please advise.

Comment: Why would you test the connector instead the results of the connection? I think you are missconcepting the UT at definition level

Comment: There may be valid reasons why you need to test what you're testing. But you're not showing us the errors. You're showing us where the exceptions were thrown but you've cut off the actual errors. What if these failing tests really indicate an error in the code? Instead of cutting and pasting pictures it's better to copy text. We don't need the whole stacktrace but at least the beginning - the exception type, message, and where it's being thrown.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm writing an unit test(using NUnit & MOQ) for a method MethodUnderTest which uses HttpContext internally to do some functionality.

Right.  Don't do that.  The controller should be the only method that accesses the HttpContext, and it should extract the data needed for your MethodUnderTest and use the to write to the HttpContext.

Structuring your code so that each method has a [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) is fundamental to writing testable code.

Comment: Hi @https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft apologies for any confusion, but MethodUnderTest  is an Action Method. I've edited my question now with the same. Thanks!